# Use of trunc in partition definition

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, create-table, partition

Why does this code work:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE(
  id                   NUMBER(10,0),                                                                  
  create_datetime      DATE           DEFAULT SYSDATE                                                  
) PARTITION BY range(create_datetime) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(7, 'DAY')) 
(PARTITION P_FIRST_PART VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2001-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))) INITRANS 12;
```

but this says error: missing right parenthesis?

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE(
  id                   NUMBER(10,0),                                                                  
  create_datetime      DATE           DEFAULT SYSDATE                                                  
) PARTITION BY range(TRUNC(create_datetime)) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(7, 'DAY')) 
(PARTITION P_FIRST_PART VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2001-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))) INITRANS 12;
```

Just changed range(create_datetime) to range(TRUNC(create_datetime))

Comment: The range specification takes a column name, not an expression. Why would you want to use `trunc()` here?

Comment: Because the create_datetime is sysdate by default and I don't want to use the hours and I don't want to change the field value

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not support expressions in the `range()` clause. Even if it did, it would be pointless to remove the time portion of the date while you are partitioning by 7 day intervals: that is, the row would still end up in the same partition anyway.

From the comments, it looks like what you actually want is a default value that does not include the time portion. If so, just change the `default` clause of the date column, like so:

```
create table example(
    id              number(10,0),                          
    create_datetime date         default trunc(sysdate) --> here
) 
partition by range(create_datetime) interval(numtodsinterval(7, 'day')) (
    partition p_first_part values less than (date '2001-01-01')
) initrans 12;
```

Comment: I'd also recommend `default on null` for column defaults as it guarantees that a default value will be set.